# Double earth on metal case light fitting Qld?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

Good morning,
We have purchased a recently renovated home, and all of the pendant lights have metal casings around where the actual bulb goes in.  The electrician we are using to rewire the house has said that whilst it has an earth wire to it, it needs to be double earthed to meet Australian Standards, so he can either rewire each one with double earth at a cost of approx $100 per light, or we buy new pendant suspension cords.
Can anyone advise if this is actually the case? Do light fittings with metal casings have to be double earthed?  Obviously we don't want anyone to be put in danger or burn the house down so we'll replace them if necessary, I'm just not sure the information is completely correct.

Comment: Just curious, if the home was recently renovated, why are you rewiring it?

Answer (score 1):

My copy of ASNZS3000:2007 has no references to 'double earth', and a cursory web search finds no useful results.

I suspect your electrician is confused (or has confused you) between 'double insulation' and 'earthing', both of which are valid but mutually exclusive means of protection against electric shock.

Most pendant lights in New Zealand, which has a similar regulatory regime to Australia, are double insulated and do not require an earth. Some electricians are not particularly comfortable with this, and he may want to earth them anyway, but this is not legally required provided they comply with the correct standards and marking.

I suggest finding another electrician.